# How to achieve smooth scrolling in Feed using UITableView for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, feed, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to develop an app which contains Feed (Home page) like Myntra/Facebook. I have used UITableView for its architecture and I am loading Images asynchronously. I have made fixed height of each cell ,But still I am not able to achieve smooth scrolling. Can anyone suggest me where am i missing? Or is there any other method to design such architecture? I think UITableview is best approach for feed type application.

Here is my code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : HomeTableViewCell!

    if dataSource[indexPath.row] == .WhatsYourEscape {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("whatsUrEscapeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        cell.whatsImage.image = UIImage(named: "my_pic")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
            var image = UIImage(named: "my_pic")
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image!.size, true, 0);
            image?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                cell.whatsImage.image = image
            })})

    }
    if dataSource[indexPath.row] == .FriendsActiviy1{
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendsActivity1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
            var image = UIImage(named : "profile_pic")
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image!.size, true, 0);
            image?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                cell.friendActivity1Image.image = image
            })})
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
            var image = UIImage(named : "book1")
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image!.size, true, 0);
            image?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
               cell.friendActivity1descImage1.image = image
            })})
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
            var image = UIImage(named : "book2")
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image!.size, true, 0);
            image?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                cell.friendActivity1descImage2.image = image
            })})
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: How are you adding your images? Can you share the code? Maybe you are trying to do it asynchronously but are using a synchronous method such as NSData(contentsOfURL: ...)?

Comment: Code posted. Please check.

Comment: Drawing in the context(UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) is an intensive function that has to be performed in the background preferably.